# Undeclared identifier for OnlyOwner modifier

Tags: solidity, modifiers

So I created a modifier to make it so for certain functions only the deployer of the contract can use the function. But once I created it, I'm getting an undeclared identifier error. Heres my constructor:

```
constructor() public{
    AdopterID =0; //increments 1 every time there is a new adopter addded
    DogID=0; //increments 1 everytime there is a new dog added
    address owner = msg.sender;
}
```

and heres my modifier that is throwing the error:

```
modifier onlyOwner(){
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the Owner");
    _;
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong? It looks basic enough that there shouldnt be any errors.

Comment: You are creating a local variable `owner` in your constructor. That's why the msg.sender is not assigned into your stored variable `owner`. Just remove the `address` type in front of the owner variable and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the owner outside of your constructor and assign it in your constructor.

```
address public owner;

constructor() public{
    AdopterID =0; //increments 1 every time there is a new adopter addded
    DogID=0; //increments 1 everytime there is a new dog added
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

constructor() public{
AdopterID =0; //increments 1 every time there is a new adopter addded
DogID=0; //increments 1 everytime there is a new dog added
address owner = msg.sender;
}

you're declaring owner variable in constructor scope. and if you wanted to use owner anywhere in contract then declare owner in global scope.

/////////////////

address owner;
constructor() public{
AdopterID =0; //increments 1 every time there is a new adopter addded
DogID=0; //increments 1 everytime there is a new dog added
owner = msg.sender;
}